# Git branch diff

Tags: git

My goal is to compare two different git branches and obtain a list of the commit logs and committers responsible for every difference between them. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Currently I'm doing this:

`git diff branch1..branch2`

Which produces the source code that is different. I can then manually `git blame` the additions, but this is laborious. I just want a list of all the commits responsible for differences (ideally the log and committer for each).

One complication, easier to explain with an example:

`branch1` has commits `A, B, C`

`branch2` has commits `D, E, F`

However, commits `B` and `E` are really the same commit (change exactly the same files--they are cherry-picks), but the log message/committer might be different. I don't want to include the `B` and `E` commits, I only want the changes that actually introduce differences between the branches.

Comment: `git shortlog` should do the job

Comment: That's a nice command, but I still need to know how to narrow to only the differences between the branches.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare to branches and see what are the differences in terms of commits, you are better served using `git log`.

There are many ways of using it. For instance, if you want to get a list of which commits are in the `origin/master` and not in `master`, you would do:

```
git log master..origin/master
```

That is called a `git revision`. There are many different ways of comparing branches, a good resource for that is [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

This gives you a list of commits. You can use all the regular modifiers to see the content (`-p`), and any other information that you might want.

Comment: I think you forgot a word in your command. Could you edit it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `..` for `git log` as well.

For your case this should do

```
git log --pretty="%h %s - %an <%ae>" branch1..branch2
```

Here,[`%h`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emhem) is abbreviated commit hash, [`%s`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emsem) is subject, [`%an`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emanem) author name and [`%ae`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emaeem) is author email. See [Pretty Formats](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#_pretty_formats) for more options.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem quite right. It's producing a massive list, way too large. It claims there are ~2500 separate commits for only 3000 lines changed, and I know that isn't true. Seems like it may be including commits that occurred in between changes, even though those commits are on both branches.

Comment: did you position the branches as per your requirements? I mean did check which branch is to place first and which to second?

Comment: Yes, I verified by producing a diff patch. If I apply the patch to branch1, it corrects the differences as I want.

Comment: I think the problem here might be that the branches have commits like this: branch1 (commits: A, B, C), branch2 (commits: D, E, F), but (B, E) are the "same" commit (they change the same files, but the log/committer may differ). I just want the commits that actually made divergence happen.

Answer (score 0):

For a list of commit logs :

as others have suggested : `git log a..b` will give the list of commits "in `b` but not in `a`".
You would have to look at both `git log a..b` and `git log b..a` to view the relevant commits.

You can also view both in one single command : `git log a...b` (three dots, meaning "symmetric difference").

You can add `--boundary` (by default, the above command does not display the commit where the branches split, adding `--boundary` shows it), `--graph` to have a better view of who is the parent of who, and `--oneline` if you want a compact overview of the lot :

```
# the --boundary and --graph are really helpful to make sense of the '...' version
git log --boundary --graph --oneline a...b

# you can use the options with any 'git log' command :
git log --graph --oneline master
git log --boundary --graph --oneline a..b
```

When viewing a symmetric difference, `git log` also has `--cherry-mark` and `-cherry-pick` options :

```
# will mark with '=' commits cherry picked between the two branches :
git log --boundary --graph --cherry-mark --oneline a...b

# will hide commits cherry picked between the two branches :
git log --boundary --graph --cherry-pick --oneline a...b
```

Read the [docs on cherry-* options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry-mark) for more details.

If you are using a graphical frontend to git, chances are you can somehow feed these options to the viewer. Most of them implicitly have the `--graph` option -- i.e : they draw lines and dots to help you follow the history of branches and merges.

In `gitk`, for example, you can do this by selecting "View > New view... (Shift-F4)" from the menu, you will have a dialog , with several options available through checkboxes, and a field "Additional arguments to git log".

---

For viewing the differences :

If you want to view the patch introduced by each commit, you can add `-p` to the `git log` commands above :

```
# with the following three views :
git log --graph --oneline --boundary --cherry-pick a...b
git log -p --graph --cherry b...a
git log -p --graph --cherry a...b
```

`--cherry` ([docs here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---cherry)) is one of the `--cherry-*` variants

You should be able to see all the info that you want (perhaps more ? ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You might have to mix diff and blame information:

https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame

Comment: This looks like it might be what I want, I'll give it a try.